# Cokriging, zero distance semivariance [gstat]

Tags: r, variogram, kriging

Trying cokriging with simulated data, I faced a problem that did not seem one in the `demo(cokriging)` with the *meuse* dataset:

I can't use `fit.lmc()` default but need to specify `fit.method=1` as the default `fit.method=7` refuses to work with "**zero distance semivariance**". This is not a trouble in itself, but I surely do something wrong and/or do not understand what I am doing... although I try to follow the textbooks ([gstat vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/vignettes/gstat.pdf), [other good ref](http://www.css.cornell.edu/faculty/dgr2/teach/R/R_ck.pdf)).

My question: my understanding of cokriging is that our interpolation of a first kind of measurement is helped by a denser, second kind of measurement. Provided that they are both present in some locations, so that regression can be done. Why then, are zero distance cross-semivariance a problem? Shouldn't it be a necessity?

Also, in textbooks, the *meuse* dataset is used without this error but measurements of the different covariates always overlap (all locations include measurements of all covariates). How then can there not be zero distance cross-semivariance?

I do hope the MWE below illustrates my misunderstanding and that someone can clarify this to me!

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
data$z1=c(rnorm(20, mean=data$x*data$y), rep(NA, 80))
data$z2=rnorm(100, mean=data$x*data$y)
cor(data$z1[1:20], data$z2[1:20])
coordinates(data) <- ~ x + y

vgm1 <- variogram(z1~1, data[1:10,])
fit1 <- fit.variogram(vgm1, vgm(psill=2, model = "Sph", 
                                range=.2, nugget=0))
plot(vgm1, fit1)
vgm2 <- variogram(z2~1, data)
fit2 <- fit.variogram(vgm2, vgm(psill=2, model = "Sph", 
                                range=.2, nugget=0))
plot(vgm2, fit2)

(g <- gstat(NULL, id = "z1", form = z1 ~ 1, data=data[1:20,], nmax=5))
(g <- gstat(g, id = "z2", form = z2 ~ 1, data=data, nmax=10))
v.cross <- variogram(g)
plot(v.cross, pl=T)
g <- gstat(g, fill.all=T, model=vgm(psill=2, model = "Sph", 
                                    range=.2, nugget=0))
(g <- fit.lmc(v.cross, g, fit.method=1, correct.diagonal = 1.01)) # works
(g <- fit.lmc(v.cross, g, correct.diagonal = 1.01)) # does not work
plot(variogram(g), model=g$model)
```